# first react native app, bypass app store?

Tags: react-native

I'm making my first app in react-native for iOS, I want friends to install it with going through expo first, just have it in their home screen, is there a way to deploy without using the app store and getting approved? if it's not for the masses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add device **UDID** in apple account then create IPA file. Using below command. It will ask you developer account credential. Make sure you've subscribe developer membership.

```
exp build:ios
```

And share link with your friend using [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/)

Comment: How to do it without expo ??

Comment: @PratikKhadka to do it with without expo you just need to generate ipa file using xcode. Once you generate IPA file from xcode you can use below link and once you generate IPA file you can just do further process of diawi

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?34616,HowTo%3A+Create+an+.ipa+file+from+XCode,

Note: to generate IPA file from xcode you would need developer account which is paid subscribe account.